# How To save colored Text in roomDatabase, on android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I can save bold, italic, and much more format, But Colored Text is not saved.
I am using RichText library. Can you help me?
thank you.

Here is my color picker code...

```
findViewById(R.id.action_txt_color).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            openColorPicker();
        });

    private void openColorPicker() {
        final ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(InputActivity.this);
        ArrayList<String>color = new ArrayList<>();
        color.add("#FF0000");
        color.add("#00FFFF");
        color.add("#0000FF");
        color.add("#00008B");
        color.add("#FFFF00");
        color.add("#00FF00");
        color.add("#C0C0C0");

        colorPicker.setOnFastChooseColorListener(new ColorPicker.OnFastChooseColorListener() {
            @Override
            public void setOnFastChooseColorListener(int position, int color) {
                editor.setTextColor(color);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                editor.removeFormat();
            }
        }).setColumns(5).show();
    }
```

Comment: Please post the exact library you are using, ideally the git link if it exists. Also post relevant code. Like your `Room Entity` and formatting object that contains the bold/italic/color states.

Comment: Why not simply add a color variable in your Entity?